# iTunes API for GIfting, not just Searching?

Tags: php, api, itunes

I'm struggling to interface with iTunes by way of automating the Gifting process for an App via a traditional website built on PHP running on linux.

Their Search API works fine, and I have also downloaded and processed the full EPF for the App store, but now need to go upstream and make requests against iTunes.  It seems like this should be a well-defined process, but I'm running into a wall and see numerous posts about the lack of a public API.

Closest I've come to a clue is this perl module:
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/LWP-UserAgent-iTMS-Client-21878.shtml
which was last updated around 2008, so no good there.

If anyone can help set me straight on this topic, it would be most appreciated!
Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 2):

Are you attempting to send your users directly to the "Gift this.." for a song or app?  This isn't currently supported by iTunes for app developers or affiliate partners, but you can reverse engineer the store to use the same urls:

Gift a song:
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard?salableAdamId=516353670&productType=S

Gift an app:
https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard?salableAdamId=479662730&productType=C

I wouldn't count on iTunes responding to questions or problems you have if they change the url structure in the future.